# Protecting bikes from elements when traveling suspended on hitch bike rack

Tags: transportation

I'll be traveling this summer (1000km each way, with one stop in between) and would like to take our bikes (4) along with us.

I have a Thule Apex installed in a 1.25" hitch that will be host to 2 mountain bikes (29er, 27.5), 1 woman's hybrid and 1 kid's mountain bike (20"). I have storage at destination.

How do I limit the impacts of the elements (rain, road debris, etc) on our bikes, most particularly the disc brakes and drive train, when traveling?

**Edit #1**

- Consider the encountered wind (ie. highway vs. storage) as reviews seem to indicate that certain products may not withstand various degrees of wind.
- Using RV in the keywords also tends to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several companies that make covers for trailer hitched bikes.  It's essentially a giant bag that's designed to cinch down over your bikes and rack. For a long trip like you are suggesting, it's probably well worth getting one.  I have seen bikes after such road trips on a rear rack coated in horrible, horrible road slime.

Comment: Do you have models/brands to suggest? Currently googling various keywords and I'm getting too much noise in the results (ie. panniers, frame bags, etc). I was able to find something from Swagman though.

Comment: I don't have any experience and wouldn't recommend any particular brand here.  However googling "hitch mount bike cover" seems to pull up a good start for me.

Comment: Ah, there you go. I wasn't using appropriate keywords it seems.

Comment: I'd get a big plastic bag, the kind that matresses come in, and put that over top of the bikes once they're on the hitch.  Wrap with plenty of tape or rope to stop it catching wind.      Another option is a roll of cling-film (saran wrap/glad wrap/ food wrap) and use that.

Comment: Both of those are good options for minimal or one time use.  However, if you plan to use one often (or want to use the bikes during your trip) I think a bag may be worth the expense.

Comment: That's funny. I just got back from a trip and was thinking about this. I ride whatever the weather so I am accustomed to maintenance. I think the only thing I would do would be to take some saran wrap, wrap around the headsets (upper and lower) and then secure the wrap with some tape. Those are the bearings most exposed to direct wind and weather and least likely to be well protected. Never done it though, and things seem fine.

Comment: @Criggie I have such a bag to try this with :) I'll have to make holes for the hitch's arms/rails though...